# XFS or ext4 filesystem mongodb server on Ubuntu machine?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, filesystems, ubuntu-16.04

As XFS is the recommended by MongoDb from following link : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/

> MongoDB on Linux
>
> Kernel and File Systems
>
> When running MongoDB in production on Linux, you should use Linux
>   kernel version 2.6.36 or later, with either the XFS or EXT4
>   filesystem. If possible, use XFS as it generally performs better with
>   MongoDB.
>
> With the WiredTiger storage engine, use of XFS is strongly recommended
>   to avoid performance issues that may occur when using EXT4 with
>   WiredTiger.
>
> With the MMAPv1 storage engine, MongoDB preallocates its database
>   files before using them and often creates large files. As such, you
>   should use the XFS or EXT4 file systems. If possible, use XFS as it
>   generally performs better with MongoDB.

And from Ubuntu link : https://askubuntu.com/questions/690360/help-me-choose-the-best-filesystem-for-my-pc

Ext4 file system is recommended for all Linux operating systems because has backwards compatibility with its predecessors, you can mount Ext2 and Ext3 as an Ext4 file system
Ext4

```
reduces file fragmentation
employs delayed allocation which helps with flash memory life as well as fragmentation.
Good choice for SSDs and HDD
```

XFS

```
Good for a media file server because of constant throughput for large files.
Most distributions require separate /boot partition because XFS and GRUB can be unpredictable
Performance with small files is not as good.
```

So which one is better to use for mongodb on ubuntu 16.04
.

Answer (score 22):

XFS is [better in general](https://hubs.ly/H08y_CT0) with WT, as the MongoDB [production notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#kernel-and-file-systems) suggest.

I ran performance benchmarks comparing XFS with EXT4 for MongoDB on AWS EC2 to find out exactly what you were wondering about. [Here](https://hubs.ly/H08y_CT0) are my results. The observation was that XFS is useful when your machine has multiple cores and fast disk that XFS can utilize. On low to mid end systems the filesystem did not make a difference.

Comment: Just had some drama with XFS - you cannot shrink xfs filesystems, so if you use LVM snapshots for backups, and you've allocated 100% of your VG for mongo, you cannot create a snapshot :/

Comment: It is good to see the how different performance is in XFS vs EXT4.

Comment: Is it good to have your main partition under an ext4 filesystem and store Mongo data on a secondary partition under an xfs filesystem ?

Comment: @HartWoom - I was wondering the same thing. Did you ever try this?

Comment: @EatenbyaGrue I remember trying this, I think I still have my server working with both partitions. Since I only have a mid tier system it does not make miracles, but it's very useful when I need to backup only the db partition. I can also easily make copies of the disk so I can mount them on my testing environment.

Comment: Thanks.  I actually did end up setting on a Linode with Ubuntu 20.04 running ext4 and NVMe block storage that I formatted with XFS for this use.  Works fine and the NVMe disk is much faster than their older rotational block storage.  So far everything seems to be working great.

Answer (score 1):

As you have said in your question, you should use XFS for MongoDB but for the general system is better ext4, so what I recommend is to have two partitions (or better two disks) one with ext4 for the system and general use, and one with XFS for MongoDB and storage of big files.